# How do I set different colors for text and underline in JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, highlighting, jtextpane

Just been trying to color the text in JTextPane - but the issue is cannot have different colors for text and the underline. How should I do that or is that even possible? The example below prints all the text and underline in RED.

```
JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();

StyleContext context = new StyleContext();

Style style = pane.addStyle("Black", null);
StyleConstants.setAlignment(style, StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT);
StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 14);
StyleConstants.setSpaceAbove(style, 4);
StyleConstants.setSpaceBelow(style, 4);
StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.BLACK);

StyledDocument document = pane.getStyledDocument();


style = pane.addStyle("Red Underline", style);
StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.RED);
StyleConstants.setUnderline(style, true);

pane.getDocument().insertString(0,  "Test String", style);
```

Comment: +1 Despite the fact that the Style API seems to be extensible, I couldn't find any documentation how to do it.

Comment: Found answer here ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502654/underline-styleconstant-in-a-different-colour-with-attributeset

Answer (score 5):

Here's the solution I found...

[Underline StyleConstant in a different colour with AttributeSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502654/underline-styleconstant-in-a-different-colour-with-attributeset)

Here's the link to sample code

http://java-sl.com/tip_colored_strikethrough.html

just changing the following line solves it ...

```
int y = a.getBounds().y + a.getBounds().height + 2 ;
```

and it works fine

Answer (score 4):

Basically there's 3 classes you need to create:

- You need to extend [javax.swing.text.LabelView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/LabelView.html) to perform modify the view however you wish (whether that's adding an colored underline or not).  You will be overriding the `paint(Graphics, Shape)` method.  You can access attributes with this line in the overridden class - the attributes should be the trigger for doing something additional to the text (like adding an underline).

  `getElement().getAttributes().getAttribute("attribute name");`
- You need to create a new [ViewFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/ViewFactory.html) and overwrite the `create` method.  It's important that when doing this you handle all element types (otherwise things won't quite display right.
- You need to create an [StyledEditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledEditorKit.html) to make tell the pane which `ViewFactory` to use.

Here's a simplified and runnable example of this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextPaneUI;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TempProject extends JPanel{


    public static void main(String args[])    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

                //Adding pane
                JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
                pane.setEditorKit(new CustomEditorKit());
                pane.setText("Underline With Different Color");

                //Set Style
                StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument)pane.getDocument();
                MutableAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
                attrs.addAttribute("Underline-Color", Color.red);
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, doc.getLength()-1, attrs, true);

                JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(pane);
                frame.setContentPane(sp);  
                frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);


            }
        });
    }

    public static class CustomEditorKit extends StyledEditorKit{

        public ViewFactory getViewFactory(){
            return new CustomUI();
        }
    }

    public static class CustomUI extends BasicTextPaneUI{
        @Override
        public View create(Element elem){
            View result = null;
            String kind = elem.getName();
            if(kind != null){
                if(kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ContentElementName)){
                    result = new MyLabelView(elem);
                } else if(kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName)){
                    result = new ParagraphView(elem);
                }else if(kind.equals(AbstractDocument.SectionElementName)){
                    result = new BoxView(elem, View.Y_AXIS);
                }else if(kind.equals(StyleConstants.ComponentElementName)){
                    result = new ComponentView(elem);
                }else if(kind.equals(StyleConstants.IconElementName)){
                    result = new IconView(elem);
                } else{
                    result = new LabelView(elem);
                }
            }else{
                result = super.create(elem);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public static class MyLabelView extends LabelView{

        public MyLabelView(Element arg0) {
            super(arg0);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g, Shape a){
            super.paint(g, a);
            //Do whatever other painting here;
            Color c = (Color)getElement().getAttributes().getAttribute("Underline-Color");
            if(c != null){
                int y = a.getBounds().y + (int)getGlyphPainter().getAscent(this);
                int x1 = a.getBounds().x;
                int x2 = a.getBounds().width + x1;

                g.setColor(c);
                g.drawLine(x1, y, x2, y);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Here's the link to another sample code:

http://java-sl.com/tip_colored_strikethrough.html

This answer is mostly for posterity, I thought adding a simplified version of the linked code and explanation would help make things more understandable.

Answer (score 2):

- [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9022901/714968), and [for Html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071389/setting-jtextpane-to-content-type-html-and-using-string-builders/9072475#9072475)
- `Document` returns model to view, there is possible to determine the index where row started / ended